# How can I get my results to display the zeros?

Tags: mysql

I have tried alot of things and I am stomped.  I know I can clean this up a little bit but I wanted to try to give as much data as possible. I split the code up so that someone can read it much better.  My results are missing 2 customer names because they have 0 gallons but I need to display them anyway in my results.  I have attached the results and desired results. Any help is welcomed.

[image]

```
select cust.name, count(distinct trx.CardNumber) as Count, Description, 
        locationid, custid, MembersMemLPI, PrgLPI 
from P2P_Monthly_Trx_TEMP trx 
    join P2P_Programs p on trx.MembersMemLPI = p.prglpi
    Left outer join P2P_Customer cust on trx.locationid = cust.custid

where trx.gallons > 0 
and trx.MembersMemLPI = '231'
and trx.CardNumber not in 
    (select distinct trx.CardNumber from P2P_Monthly_Trx_TEMP trx
    where trx.gallons = 0 
    and trx.MembersMemLPI = '231'
    )

group by cust.name, Description, locationid, custid, MembersMemLPI, PrgLPI
order by cust.name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn the query around and make P2P_Customer the required table, and P2P_Monthly_Trx_TEMP the optional table:

```
select cust.name, count(distinct trx.CardNumber) as Count, Description, 
        locationid, custid, MembersMemLPI, PrgLPI 
  from P2P_Customer cust
  Left outer join P2P_Monthly_Trx_TEMP trx
    on trx.locationid = cust.custid AND
  left join P2P_Programs p
    on trx.MembersMemLPI = p.prglpi AND
       trx.gallons > 0 and
       trx.MembersMemLPI = '231' and
       trx.CardNumber not in (select distinct trx.CardNumber from P2P_Monthly_Trx_TEMP trx
                                where trx.gallons = 0 and
                                      trx.MembersMemLPI = '231')
  group by cust.name, Description, locationid, custid, MembersMemLPI, PrgLPI
  order by cust.name ASC
```

Comment: This actually gave me 2,806 rows so it did not work unfortunately, I am still trying to see what i can do to get this correct.  Thank you though.  The P2P_Monthly_Trx_TEMP table has the cardnumber, gallons, locationid, membersmemlpi in it so that is why i used that as the required table, I am only getting cust.name from Customer table and description from Programs table.  Customer table has custid which is the same as locationid in the  P2P_Monthly_Trx_TEMP table and Programs table has PrgLPI which is the same as Membersmemlpi in the  P2P_Monthly_Trx_TEMP table